# Click on buttons one by one

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

This is my HTML code. I have a list of buttons.

```
<button class= "message-anywhere-button mn-connection-card__message-btn button-secondary-medium" aria-label="hello" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-62="62">
<span aria-hidden="true"> Msg</span>
<span class="visually-hidden"> hello</span>
```

I want to click on "Msg" Buttons one by one.
I am using selenium and this is my code `number=10`

```
for x in number:
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".button-secondary-medium").click()
```

It is accessing only the first button 10 times. After accessing the first button, I want to access the second one, and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use indexes as you have mentioned `for x in number:` you need to use `range`.Try this.

```
elements=driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".button-secondary-medium")
for x in range(len(elements)):
    elements[x].click()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put all elements into a variable and use them in a loop.

```
all_elems = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".button-secondary-medium")

for elem in all_elems:
    if elem.is_displayed():
        elem.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below snippet

```
xButtons = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('your class name')

for x in xButtons:
 x.click()
 browser.back() // if clicking a button navigates to diff page
```

Cheers!